# What caused this error: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file named database.php. Inside of that file:

```
database_useranme = "ferdinel";
database_sixtysec = "ferdinel_db";
```

Now I made a script to get the database 'ferdinel_db', Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#To get the line that has a "database_sixtysec ="
getdb=`grep "database_sixtysec =" < /www/vhost/database.php`

# To verify Output what's inside in get_db
echo "$getdb"   

# This one is to get the ferdinel_db
databaseName=`echo ${getdb#*\"} | tr -d '"; '`         

#Below is to count the file if exist in $databaseName variable (ferdinel_db)
countFlag=`ls /var/lib/mysql/$databaseName | grep 'sixty_options.frm\|site_settings.frm' | wc -l` 

#Ouput Either 0 , 1 or 2
echo $countFlag
```

Then I `chmod +x` with `chown root:root` the script.

Now when I try to run it, the output is:

```
$database_sixtysec = "ferdinel_db";
: No such file or directory_db
0
```

I expect for 2 because there are **sixty_options.frm** and **site_settings.frm** there when I manually viewed in /var/lib/mysql/ferdinel_db/

I add **-x** at the end of `#!/bin/bash` and this what output:

```
' getdb='$database_sixtysec = "ferdinel_db";
'+ echo 'ferdinel_db";
++ tr -d '"; '
+ databaseName=$'ferdinel_db\r'
' echo '$database_sixtysec = "ferdinel_db";
$database_sixtysec = "ferdinel_db";
++ ls $'/var/lib/mysql/ferdinel_db\r'
++ grep 'sixty_options.frm\|site_settings.frm'
++ wc -l
: No such file or directorycssv25_db
```

There's something at the end of the db something like **\r**

Comment: Are you using Cygwin?

Comment: your problem is here: databaseName=`echo ${getdb#*\"} | tr -d '"; '`

Comment: Not related to your problem:  It looks there's a typo in `database_useranme = "ferdinel";` - either way, the variable

Comment: Hi @Henk, It will not matter because, all I need to get is the `database_sixtysec = "ferdinel_db";`

Answer (score 5):

Your script has CRLF endings. Try to fix it with `dos2unix` or the settings in your editor.

Comment: If you don't have `dos2unix`, run this: `perl -pi -e 's@\r$@@' script.sh`

Comment: Or sed: `sed -i 's|\r$||' file`

Comment: I'll try it and inform to you guys. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change the top line of your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

And run it.  That will give you a much better idea of what's going on in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out!

First in order what really happened I add `-x` at the end of `#!/bin/bash`.

`#!/bin/bash -x`

And when I run it, you can view all the process and this is the output:

```
' getdb='$database_sixtysec = "ferdinel_db";
'+ echo 'ferdinel_db";
++ tr -d '"; '
+ databaseName=$'ferdinel_db\r'
' echo '$database_sixtysec = "ferdinel_db";
$database_sixtysec = "ferdinel_db";
++ ls $'/var/lib/mysql/ferdinel_db\r'
++ grep 'sixty_options.frm\|site_settings.frm'
++ wc -l
: No such file or directorycssv25_db
```

I saw \r at the end of the `+ databaseName=$'ferdinel_db\r'`. And research about this, this is what we called **Windows carriage returns** because the file was edited in windows.

So to eliminate `\r` at the end of `ferdinel_db`, I add `\r` at the `tr -d '"; '`

```
databaseName=`echo ${getdb#*\"} | tr -d '"; \r'`
```

And this solve my problem. Thanks to all your help!

Comment: I'm glad we could help solve your issue.  It would be nice if you accepted @konsolebox's answer, since he pointed out the problem.